# Unable to dismiss BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using following approach to create bottomsheet dialog, dialog is creating but I want to dismiss on backpress for that all setup I'm using the code below. But not doing able to dismiss dialog.

```
 class MainActivity : BaseClass(), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
             bottomSheetDialog=BottomSheetDialog(this)
             create.setOnClickListener { 
               createBottomSheetDialog()
              }
    }
 override fun onBackPressed() {
            if (bottomSheetDialog.isShowing){
                bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
            }
            super.onBackPressed()
        }

     private fun createBottomSheetDialog(){
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog)
        bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false)
        bottomSheetDialog.show()

    }
}
```

I have been tried using `this.bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()`
but not working I also have try dismissing the dialog without if statement and without using `super.onBackPressed()` but not working.

Comment: did you try only `dismiss();` ? or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47607064/10182897) code

Comment: Ok let me check if it actually works. You mean use only dismiss() in onBackPressed() method without any instance of BottomSheetDialog

Comment: @Ashish only dismiss will end the activity.

Comment: bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false) remove this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply remove this line from your code

```
bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false)
```

You can get more details about this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog#setCancelable(boolean)). I guess you need to stop dismiss when clicked anywhere outside the fragment so you can add this :-

```
bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

It will allow you to dismiss `onBackPressed` but it won't allow you to dismiss if clicked anywhere outside of your bottom sheet.

Also no need to write this in your `Main activity` :-

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (bottomSheetDialog.isShowing){
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
        }
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

Bottom Sheet dialogue will itself dismiss `onBackPressed`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (bottomSheetDialog.isShowing){
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shashank Pandey You can write a Log to check if `onBackPressed()` actually gets called when you press the back button, then check the `isShowing()` value to make sure it is true, step by step to narrow down the problem source.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting global variable for activity `dialog: BottomSheetDialog? = null`

Then in the function for displaying dialog give it a value and show it. Then in onCreate (or whenever you want) just use global variable as a reference eg.:

```
onBackPressed(){
if(dialog != null){
dialog.dismiss()}}
```